# Is there a way to make first commit after initial commit not count in terms of contribution graph?

Tags: git, github

Basically for my first commit I'm copying files I have into this newly created repository and since I'm not actually writing code I'd like these lines of code not count for my contributions in Insight > Contributors. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Fork the repo instead.

Answer (score 0):

Beside forking, another tip would be:

- make your initial commit on a different orphan branch
- make your first master commit as empty
- make a merge non-ff from the orphan branch to master

The [GitHub page "Viewing contribution activity in a repository"](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contribution-activity-in-a-repository/) does mention:

> Merge commits and commits that don't include changes aren't included in this graph.